# Replace filename with filepath with sed

Tags: shell, regex, sed

I want to replace the string

`/opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/cucumber-0.3.99/lib/cucumber.rb`

with the string

`/opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/cucumber-0.3.99/lib/`

on the command line, probably using sed. I can't for the life of me figure out the replacement regex to pass to sed. Or maybe sed isn't even the right tool for the job. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

no need for sed:

`dirname /usr/local/bin/program`

will return /usr/local/bin

Comment: There is not even any need for `dirname` :-) . If the string is stored in `$MYPROGRAM`, then `${MYPROGRAM%/*}` strips everything including and after the last slash, leaving you with the path to `MYPROGRAM`. This expansion behaviour is defined by POSIX. `dirname` handles relative paths and things like multiple slashes better, though.

Comment: Neat!  Which version of bash does it need to work?  `dirname` is old and standard enough that it will work just about anywhere.

Comment: @Marcin: it works with any Bash version; it is supposed to work with every standards (=POSIX) honoring shell. Also, on a separate note, if you respond to someone among the comments: if you start the comment with "@username", that user will be notified of the response through the site (I just found my comment by chance now, a week later).